# Delphi DX Seattle - Cant Post Application Exception to SQLite DB using TFDTable

Tags: sqlite, delphi, firemonkey, firedac

The same code works fine in XE8 doesn't work in DX Seattle hoping it just needs some other setting

I wanted to log exceptions into a database table using SQLite
Adding data into the table using the AddData call below works fine for a normal button click
but I cant get the SQLite database to add data from the Application.OnException call
using the debugger looks like it adds the line but it seems to delete itself
behaving like its in a transaction and it auto rolls back

does anyone know why this isn't posting?

```
procedure TForm1.AppException(Sender: TObject; e: Exception);
begin
  AddData(e.Message); //<--- this line gets called on exception but not adding data
  Application.ShowException(e);
end;

procedure TForm1.AddData(aString: String);
begin
  tb1.Append;
  tb1.FieldByName('test').AsString := aString;
  tb1.Post;
  tb1.Close;
  con1.close();
  con1.Open();
  tb1.Open();
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddData('btn1Click');  //this Works
end;

procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  raise Exception.Create('Error Message'); //cant get this to add into the DB
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  con1.Open();
  if con1.Connected then begin
    qry1.SQL.Clear;
    qry1.SQL.Add
   ('Create Table if not Exists TEST(test char(255));');
    qry1.ExecSQL;
    tb1.Open();
  end;
  Application.OnException := AppException;
end;
```

Full code here
https://github.com/dangas56/DelphiDXSeattle-ApplicationOnException-SQLite

Steps to reproduce from the code in git
1 - Load Project
2 - Click the "Adds data to DB" button <-- should work
3 - Click the "fails to add to DB" button <-- fails to add line

---

Seems to be something funny with the FDTable component
ive changed the way the AddData call is working above

```
procedure TForm1.AddData(aString: String);
  procedure AddUsingFDTable(aStr : String);  <--Fails
  var tbTest : TFDTable;
  begin
    tbTest := TFDTable.Create(nil);
    try
      tbTest.UpdateOptions.AutoCommitUpdates := true;
      tbTest.UpdateOptions.UpdateMode := upWhereAll;
      tbTest.Connection := con1;
      tbTest.TableName := 'TEST';
      tbTest.Open();
      tbTest.Append;
      tbTest.FieldByName('test').AsString := aStr;
      tbTest.Post;
      tbTest.Close;
    finally
      tbTest.Free;
    end;
  end;

  procedure AddusingFDQuery(aStr : String);  <--Works
  var qry1 : TFDQuery;
  begin
    qry1 := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
    try
      qry1.Connection := con1;
      qry1.SQL.Clear;
      qry1.SQL.Add('insert into test (test) values ( :Testing )');
      qry1.ParamByName('Testing').AsString := aStr;
      qry1.ExecSQL;
    finally
      qry1.Free;
    end;
  end;

begin
  AddUsingFDTable(aString);  <--Fails
  //AddusingFDQuery(aString);  <--Works

  tb1.Close;
  con1.close();
  con1.Open();
  tb1.Open();
end;
```

can anyone tell me why the table component isn't posting when being called from this?

```
procedure TForm1.AppException(Sender: TObject; e: Exception);
begin
  AddData(e.Message); //<--- this line gets called on exception but not adding data
  Application.ShowException(e);
end;
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the down vote? if there is ill try and fix it up

Comment: And what about the `CachedUpdates` flag? What if you call `tbTest.ApplyUpdates;`/`CommitUpdates`? The documentation says: "To change the CachedUpdate property value for TFDTable, it must be inactive."

Comment: CachedUpdates was set to false, tried using it but it didn't make any difference